# GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer cache HashMap<Integer,String> as HashMap<String,String>

Tags: java, redis

I have a simple springboot application with redisTemplate.
My redisTemplate configuration is

```
   `ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.enable(JsonGenerator.Feature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN);
    objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    objectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(objectMapper.getPolymorphicTypeValidator(),           ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);


    RedisSerializer<String> stringSerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
    GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer objectSerializer = new      GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper);

    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(getJedisConnectionFactory());
    template.setKeySerializer(stringSerializer);
    template.setValueSerializer(objectSerializer);

    template.setHashKeySerializer(stringSerializer);
    template.setHashValueSerializer(objectSerializer);

    template.setEnableDefaultSerializer(true);
    template.afterPropertiesSet();
    return template;`
```

My dao class is :

```
`public class RedisOperations {
     private RedisTemplate<String,Object> redisTemplate;
     private HashOperations<String, Object, Object> hashOperations;
     private ValueOperations<String, Object> opsForValue;

@Autowired
public void RedisServiceImpl(RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate) {
    this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
    
}

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    hashOperations = redisTemplate.opsForHash();
    opsForValue = redisTemplate.opsForValue();
}

public Object getAllValue(String key) {
    return opsForValue.get(key);
}

public void saveAllValue(String key, Object value) {
    opsForValue.set(key, value);
}

}`
```

I can cache java HashMap to redis properly.I can see the json result on redis Desktop manager.But in my java application  map.get(2) gives null but map.get("2") gives value properly.

Dou you have any idea how I cache data to redis as HashMap<Integer,String>

I tried 3-4 difference library for redis serializaitons but result is same :(